# Flutter android app not running with mobile data

Tags: android, flutter, networking

My flutter android application working fine with WiFi but when ever I tried to use my mobile data, an error occurred.
ERROR:

```
E/flutter (16859): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Connection failed
E/flutter (16859): #0      IOClient.send (package:http/src/io_client.dart:88:7)
E/flutter (16859): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (16859): #1      BaseClient._sendUnstreamed (package:http/src/base_client.dart:93:32)
E/flutter (16859): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (16859): #2      _withClient (package:http/http.dart:164:12)
E/flutter (16859): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (16859): #3      DashboardRepository.getDashboardSummaryResponse (package:my_app/repositories/screen_repository.dart:11:22)
E/flutter (16859): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (16859): #4      _HomeState.myfunction(package:my_app/screens/screen.dart:102:20)
E/flutter (16859): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (16859):
```

I needed to run my app with both (WiFi and Mobile data)..

Answer (score 0):

Go to android -> app -> src -> main -> AndroidManifest.xml.

add this line to it before application:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

<application ......